# Passing redux state and props to another component using react Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a scenario where I want to open a particular URL in new tab when user clicks on particular button. I've used window.open("/itemPage", '_blank'); for opening new tab. but I'm not able to pass data to particular component through react router.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import ItemPageComponent from './ItemPageComponent';
import history from '../history';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';

class RouterComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log("CCTV cameraInfoFrame:: " + this.props.item.name);

        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact
                                path="/"
                                component={Home}
                            />
                            <Route exact
                                path="/itemPage"
                                    component={<ItemPageComponent data={ this.props.item} />}
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.PopoutReducer.itemDetailsState
});

const RouterContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(RouterComponent);

export default RouterContainer;
```

Can anyone help me out for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are the props passed to `RouterComponent` come from ?

Comment: And how "*much*" data do you want to pass ? a single string like `name` or an object like `item` ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I've updated the complete code snippet.

Comment: I want to pass item object. whenever I'm passing string value then I'm able to read it in another component. but I want to pass item object.